# Linked Server Querying

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have the table name which is in the linked server.How to write a T-SQL query to find the database name (In linked server) from that table name?
I have no idea about linked server querying.Kindly help me
Thank you.

Comment: If you know it's SQL Server why did you tag mysql... Please use the correct tags. Also, this information is easily found via google.

Comment: Sorry for that Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM <linkedservername>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM <linkedservername>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XXXXX'
```

or

```
select * from <linkedservername>.master.sys.databases
```

for get a list of all Databases

Comment: I will try.Thanks for that Frank.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (nameoflinkedserver).INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM LinkServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName

Example

Select * from MYLINKSERVER.MYDATABASE.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE